# Win 7 mapping to NAS only works by IP, not UNC

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, nas, samba, synology

Windows 7 pro desktop.  Last night (maybe after an update) I lost the ability to map drives to our new Synology NAS (running DSM 5.1) by UNC (\diskstation\homes\user).  After many reboots and much troubleshooting I found I can map to it by IP address (\192.168.1.11\homes\user).

UNC shares to our network server (W2K12) and an older Synology NAS (running DSM 3.x) work fine.

Other systems in our office (Win 7 Pro, Home and XP) CAN map to the new NAS via UNC fine - only I lost the ability.  The one unique factor of my PC is that I'm the only domain user on the W2K12 server - all other people are work group users.

I followed some unhelpful error messages on Google and saw something about secure negotiations in Samba.  The NAS has "Use Samba 2" checked in it's file sharing system.  Couple my being a domain user have changed the requirements for my PC and somehow disabled Samba 2?

Comment: Are you using the same DNS server as the users in the workgroup?  What is the actual error you get when trying to map to it by name?  If you perform an `nslookup diskstation` from the problematic machine, what does it return?

Comment: My PC's DNS is set to the IP address of the W2K12 server.  Since I'm the only domain user, the others are set to the Fios router.  However, the W2K12 server has no problems seeing or connecting to the NAS, only my PC.  `nslookup diskstation` returns "non-existent domain"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on what you've said here's my guess/suggestions...

Assumptions/guesses about configuration:

- Your "Diskstation" NAS is using DHCP to get it's IP.
- Your DHCP is being handed out by your router, and in those DHCP settings it's giving out itself as the DNS server for clients to use.
- Your router is aware of the host names of the devices that requested DHCP from it, and it adds those host names to its internal name (DNS) records.
- Anyone using the router as their DNS server will have those host names resolved.
- Your PC is using the Windows server as its DNS server.
- You have no record in your Windows DNS server for the "Diskstation" host.
- You Windows DNS server is not setup to forward unknown requests to the router.
- Therefor any machine that requests a name lookup for the "Diskstation" host from the Window DNS server isn't going to get an address returned.

Short Solution 1):

- Set your PC to use the router as its DNS.

While this will work, it's a bad idea, as this will *greatly* slow down your domain logins while it tries to find the Domain Controller (usually quickly found via a DNS lookup).

Short Solution 2):

- Setup the Windows DNS server to forward requests for unknown hosts to the router.

The router will get those requests that the Windows DNS doesn't have entries for, and answer with the right IP (if it's a host the router knows about, which the Diskstaiton should be).

Suggestion solution:

1. Setup DHCP on the Windows server.
2. Disable the DCHP server in the router.
3. Configure Windows DHCP to be allowed to update DNS records of the Windows DNS server.
4. Configure windows DHCP to hand out the Windows server as the primary/only DNS server for clients to use.
5. Setup the Windows DNS server to forward requests for unknown hosts to the router, or directly to your ISP's DNS (or a public one like Google's or OpenDNS or whatever).

By using the Windows DHCP integrated with Windows' DNS server means that you can/will have DNS entries automatically added/updated for any devices that successfully use the DHCP server (ie: your NAS).

As above, the Windows DNS will try to answer first, and if it doesn't have a record for that host it'll pass it up the DNS server chain.

Answer (score 0):

Configure WINS, DNS. Configure the firewall on Windows 7. If you configure the VLAN and the station is connected to the Windows 7 W2K12, then configure the firewall to W2K12, or for example if the NAS is owned subnet in DMZ. Perhaps you will have to configure the protocol SMB. Look at the properties of the NetBT and correct them. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the domain for WINS/DNS and you're the only one having issues chances are that the new Syn isn't registering in the domain's WINS database.  If your workgroup users already have [corrsponding] user names locally on the nas then the simplest solution is probably to just join the NAS to your domain.  This will force the NAS to register with WINS which will solve your problem.  Workgroup users will continue to see/find the nas via unc broadcast.